# How I can have different background color in different expandable ListView Group in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a Tab Layout, each layout has a expandable ListView, each ListView has its BaseExpandableListAdapter. I want for each group a different background. How I am supposed to change my Adapter to achieve this?

```
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.off_group, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}
```

I tried the suggested, and I declare the int color array with hex colors globally! like

```
private int[] colors = {Color.parseColor("#b8dbd3"), Color.parseColor("#ffe975"), Color.parseColor("#dbdcff"), Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5"), Color.parseColor("#ccd6dd")};

public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.off_group, null);
    }
    Random ranndom = new Random();
    int ranndomColor = ranndom.nextInt(5);
    LinearLayout GroupLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ParentGroup);
    GroupLayout.setBackgroundResource(colors[ranndomColor]);

    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}
```

but I get an error on resource

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffff00
```

Comment: I ve try the cleaning :) already the same thing.. It doesnt like the GroupLayout.setBackgroundResource(colors[ranndomColor]);

Comment: I should have typed setBackgroundColor(colors[randomColor]) not Background Resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:**

```
 private int[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN};

 Random ranndom = new Random();
 int ranndomColor = ranndom.nextInt(5);
 whatever.setBackground(colors[ranndomColor]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
LinearLayout GroupLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ParentGroup);
    GroupLayout.setBackgroundColor(colors[listPosition]);
```

thank you